# HTML templates not getting rendered in django

Tags: django

I am new at django and I have an app in django project. My base.html has navigation bar through which you can redirect to "about", 'contact us', 'home'.
The first page when app starts (after loging in) is home.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  {%load staticfiles%}
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ekyam: India's First Entrepreneurial Ecosystem</title>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <meta content="" name="keywords">
  <meta content="" name="description">



  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS File -->
  <link href="{% static "visit/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Libraries CSS Files -->
  <link href="{% static "visit/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static "visit/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static "visit/lib/owlcarousel/owl.theme.min.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static "visit/lib/owlcarousel/owl.transitions.min.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Main Stylesheet File -->
  <link href="{%static "visit/css/style.css"%}" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--Your custom colour override - predefined colours are: colour-blue.css, colour-green.css, colour-lavander.css, orange is default-->
  <link href="#" id="colour-blue" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="page-index has-hero">
  <!--Change the background class to alter background image, options are: benches, boots, buildings, city, metro -->
  <div id="background-wrapper" class="city" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.1">

    <!-- ======== @Region: #navigation ======== -->


    <div id="navigation" class="wrapper">
      <!--Hidden Header Region-->
      <div class="header-hidden collapse">
        <div class="header-hidden-inner container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <h3>
                  About Us
                </h3>
              <p>Ekyam is dedicated to support and nourish Startups and accelaration</p>
              <a href="about.html" class="btn btn-more"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Learn more</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <!--@todo: replace with company contact details-->
              <h3>
                  Contact Us
                </h3>
              <address>
                  <strong>EKYAM</strong>
                  <abbr title="Address"><i class="fa fa-pushpin"></i></abbr>
                  MMMDU, Mullana, Ambala- Haryana
                  <br>
                  <abbr title="Phone"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></abbr>
                  8219984448
                  <br>
                  <abbr title="Email"><i class="fa fa-envelope-alt"></i></abbr>
                  info@ekyam.com
                </address>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <!--Colour & Background Switch for demo - @todo: remove in production-->
              <h3>
                  Theme Variations
                </h3>
              <div class="switcher">
                <div class="cols">
                  Backgrounds:
                  <br>
                  <a href="#benches" class="background benches active" title="Benches">Benches</a> <a href="#boots" class="background boots " title="Boots">Boots</a> <a href="#buildings" class="background buildings " title="Buildings">Buildings</a>
                  <a
                    href="#city" class="background city " title="City">City</a> <a href="#metro" class="background metro " title="Metro">Metro</a>
                </div>
                <div class="cols">
                  Colours:
                  <br>
                  <a href="#orange" class="colour orange active" title="Orange">Orange</a> <a href="#green" class="colour green " title="Green">Green</a> <a href="#blue" class="colour blue " title="Blue">Blue</a> <a href="#lavender" class="colour lavender "
                    title="Lavender">Lavender</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>
                <small>Selection is not persistent.</small>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--Header & navbar-branding region-->
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-inner container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <!--navbar-branding/logo - hidden image tag & site name so things like Facebook to pick up, actual logo set via CSS for flexibility -->
              <a class="navbar-brand" title="Home" href = "{% url "visit:index"%}">
                <h1 class="hidden">
                    <h1>EKYAM</h1>
                  </h1>
              </a>
              <br/>
              <div class="navbar-slogan">
                Hub Of StartUp
                <br> By The Brogrammers
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--header rightside-->
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <!--user menu-->
              <ul class="list-inline user-menu pull-right">

              </ul>
              <ul class="list-inline user-menu pull-right">
                <li class="user-register"><i class="fa fa-edit text-primary "></i> <a href="{% url "visit:registration"%}" class="text-uppercase">Register</a></li>
                <li class="user-login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in text-primary"></i> <a href="{%url "visit:login"%}" class="text-uppercase">Login</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default">
          <!--mobile collapse menu button-->
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>

          <!--everything within this div is collapsed on mobile-->
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-menu">
              <li class="icon-link">
                <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Comunity<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-header"> </li>
                  <li><a href="elements.html" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a href="about.html" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">About Us</a></li>
                  <li><a href="login.html" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">Login</a></li>
                  <li><a href="register.html" tabindex="-1" class="menu-item">Sign-Up</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-footer">Connect</li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="{% url "visit:registration"%}">Join Us</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown dropdown-mm">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Mega Menu<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-mm dropdown-menu-persist">
                  <li class="row">
                    <ul class="col-md-6">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Websites and Apps</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Analysis and Planning</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">User Experience / Information Architecture</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">User Interface Design / UI Design</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Code &amp; Development / Implementation &amp; Support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="col-md-6">
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Enterprise solutions</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Business Analysis</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Custom UX Consulting</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Quality Assurance</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-7">Like the lite version? <strong>Get the extended version of Flexor.</strong></div>
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <a href="https://bootstrapmade.com" class="btn btn-more btn-lg pull-right"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i> Get It Now</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hero" id="highlighted">
      <div class="inner">
        <!--Slideshow-->
        <div id="highlighted-slider" class="container">
          <div class="item-slider" data-toggle="owlcarousel" data-owlcarousel-settings='{"singleItem":true, "navigation":true, "transitionStyle":"fadeUp"}'>
            <!--Slideshow content-->
            <!--Slide 1-->

{%block content%}
{%endblock%}

</div>
                <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs">
                  <img src="img/slides/slide2.png" alt="Slide 2" class="center-block img-responsive">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer id="footer" class="block block-bg-grey-dark" data-block-bg-img="img/bg_footer-map.png" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.4">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row" id="contact">

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <address>
              <strong>JunityMe Inc</strong>
              <br>
              <i class="fa fa-map-pin fa-fw text-primary"></i> Maharishi Markendeshver Engineering College
              <br>
              <i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw text-primary"></i> 8219984448
              <br>
              <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw text-primary"></i> info@junity.com
              <br>
            </address>
        </div>



      <a href="#top" class="scrolltop">Top</a>

    </div>
  </footer>
```

The problem is, only this template is getting rendered. When I click on the other options on the navigation bar, the url changer(/incubator/) but the template remains the same.

urls.py:
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

```
app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'incubators/', views.incubators, name='incubators'),
    url(r'about/', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

I don't see any kinds of error. Somehow I think my urls are unable to connect to views.py.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'main/home.html')


def incubators(request):
    return render(request, 'main/incubators.html')


def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("dsfsddsf")
```

Please suggest edits if I can make it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
    url(r'^', views.home, name='home'),
```

The `^` sign means *start of url* so that matches all urls that *have a start*, i.e every url. So any URL will be rendered by views.home.

move that one to the bottom of the list, Then it will only match anything when all the other URLs have tried and it will do what you want.

If you really want to match only / then add

```
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
```

`$` means the *end* of an url, so that matches where there is nothing at all between the start and the end, i.e a empty url path

Comment: Thanks a lot man you are a life saver I had to submit the project today..

Comment: The please mark my post as correct answer so it's not showing up as unanswered.